# Issue with 'matplotlib.mlab' in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins

When I open QGIS I get the following error:

```
Couldn't load plugin 'rastertool' due to an error when calling its classFactory() method 

ImportError: cannot import name 'griddata' from 'matplotlib.mlab' (C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mlab.py).
```

I downloaded the last version of QGIS 3.12.1 'București' for windows 10. Actually, I downloaded the OSGeo4W Network Installer (64bit).

I am not familiar with python, so could you please help me how to solve it and install it in python?

Comment: This plug-in may not work with the latest qgis version. Did you try to re-install the plug-in ?

Comment: I have seen that there is a problem with this one. However, how can re-install plugin-in? and are you sure that this the problem?

Comment: In the plugin manager window when you select a plugin there are options to uninstall or re-install. Anyway, it won't help, I have tried also installing RasterTool.  I suggest to report the bug here: https://github.com/aishwaryahegde29/RasterTool_Qgis/issues .  Also, This is the plugin page at Qgis plugins website: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/rastertool/ . maybe you can try install the previous versin of the plugin (0.1) .